# Running Hydra from IDE

Tags: python, ide, spyder, fb-hydra

That may seem a naive question, but is there a way to run use Hydra from an IDE?

I am interested in using it within anaconda spyder, but if there is way to run experiments with hydra from another IDE I wouldn't mind to change.

Also is there any other similar framework/package for organising research results?

I tried searching on internet but didn't find a relevant answer.

Comment: Please add context as to what exactly you are hoping to achieve.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.